# JSLink, implementation of sp.runtime.js

Tags: client-object-model, jslink, client-side-rendering

I want to override my field using `SP.Guid.newGuid()`, but SharePoint loading my custom js file earlier than `sp.runtime.js` file.

There are best practice for implementation of `sp.runtime.js` in this case?

```
  (function () {
    var overrideFields = {};
    overrideFields.Templates = {};
    overrideFields.Templates.Fields = {
        'MyDD': {
            'NewForm': viewOverride,
            'EditForm': viewOverride,
            'DisplayForm': viewOverride,
            'View': viewOverride
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideFields);
    }());

    function viewOverride() {
        var toView = '<div><span>' + SP.Guid.newGuid() + '</span></div>';
        return toView;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try:
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourFunction, "sp.js")

Comment: Marco, yes i was trying.

Answer (score 0):

Modify as below

```
(function () {
    var overrideFields = {};
    overrideFields.Templates = {};
    overrideFields.Templates.Fields = {
        'MyDD': {
            'NewForm': viewOverride,
            'EditForm': viewOverride,
            'DisplayForm': viewOverride,
            'View': viewOverride
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideFields);
    }()
);

function viewOverride() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {
        var toView = '<div><span>' + SP.Guid.newGuid() + '</span></div>';
        return toView;
    });        
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working.